# An error has occurred while configuring VirtualBox host-only network interface "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2

Tags: genymotion

After successfully installing VirtualBox and Genymotion, I can't start genymotion and it gives this error:

```
An error has occurred while configuring VirtualBox host-only network interface "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled VirtualBox and also tried disabling antivirus but still problem persists.
There is no `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter` existing in network adapters list and it seems that Genymotion can't create it.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled VirtualBox again

and then reinstalled it but this time I installed it **as Administrator** and then do a **restart**.

so the network adapters could get created and error solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix i think while hit and trail:

Open Virtual Box and go to File -> Tools -> Network Manager

[image]

I clicked create network and it did not do anything else except adding #2 number network which was not even configured and working,
Then i ran genymotion (i think as admin, not sure) and now the error was fixed.